# C# JSON decentralization for OCR Response

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm using OCR API to capture text in an image. I want to deserialize the JSON response and extract each word from each line. No words are showing up when I run `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject`
Any help is appreciated!
Here's the response:

```
{
  "language": "en",
  "textAngle": -2.0000000000000338,
  "orientation": "Up",
  "regions": [
    {
      "boundingBox": "462,379,497,258",
      "lines": [
        {
          "boundingBox": "462,379,497,74",
          "words": [
            {
              "boundingBox": "462,379,41,73",
              "text": "A"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "523,379,153,73",
              "text": "GOAL"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "694,379,265,74",
              "text": "WITHOUT"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "boundingBox": "565,471,289,74",
          "words": [
            {
              "boundingBox": "565,471,41,73",
              "text": "A"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "626,471,150,73",
              "text": "PLAN"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "801,472,53,73",
              "text": "IS"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "boundingBox": "519,563,375,74",
          "words": [
            {
              "boundingBox": "519,563,149,74",
              "text": "JUST"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "683,564,41,72",
              "text": "A"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "741,564,153,73",
              "text": "WISH"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: @BrianRogers Can you help in extracting the words?

Answer (score 2):

There is a NuGet package already available for the Microsoft Azure OCR :

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Vision.ComputerVision
```

You can then include the OcrResult model class provided by the package:

```
using Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Vision.ComputerVision.Models;
```

Deserialize the JSON response to the model type and extract the text in each OcrLine object.

```
OcrResult ocrResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OcrResult>(JSONResult);

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

if (!ocrResult.Language.Equals("unk"))
{
      foreach (OcrLine ocrLine in ocrResult.Regions[0].Lines)
      {
         foreach (OcrWord ocrWord in ocrLine.Words)
         {
                sb.Append(ocrWord.Text);
                sb.Append(' ');
         }
       sb.AppendLine();
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The example looks like

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace Rextester
{
    public class Rootobject
    {
        public string language { get; set; }
        public float textAngle { get; set; }
        public string orientation { get; set; }
        public Region[] regions { get; set; }
    }

    public class Region
    {
        public string boundingBox { get; set; }
        public Line[] lines { get; set; }
    }

    public class Line
    {
        public string boundingBox { get; set; }
        public Word[] words { get; set; }
    }

    public class Word
    {
        public string boundingBox { get; set; }
        public string text { get; set; }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string val = "{\n" +
                "    \"language\": \"en\",\n" +
                "    \"textAngle\": -2.0000000000000338,\n" +
                "    \"orientation\": \"Up\",\n" +
                "    \"regions\": [\n" +
                "        {\n" +
                "            \"boundingBox\": \"462,379,497,258\",\n" +
                "            \"lines\": [\n" +
                "                {\n" +
                "                    \"boundingBox\": \"462,379,497,74\",\n" +
                "                    \"words\": [\n" +
                "                        {\n" +
                "                            \"boundingBox\": \"462,379,41,73\",\n" +
                "                            \"text\": \"A\"\n" +
                "                        },\n" +
                "                        {\n" +
                "                            \"boundingBox\": \"523,379,153,73\",\n" +
                "                            \"text\": \"GOAL\"\n" +
                "                        },\n" +
                "                        {\n" +
                "                            \"boundingBox\": \"694,379,265,74\",\n" +
                "                            \"text\": \"WITHOUT\"\n" +
                "                        }\n" +
                "                    ]\n" +
                "                },\n" +
                "                {\n" +
                "                    \"boundingBox\": \"565,471,289,74\",\n" +
                "                    \"words\": [\n" +
                "                        {\n" +
                "                            \"boundingBox\": \"565,471,41,73\",\n" +
                "                            \"text\": \"A\"\n" +
                "                        },\n" +
                "                        {\n" +
                "                            \"boundingBox\": \"626,471,150,73\",\n" +
                "                            \"text\": \"PLAN\"\n" +
                "                        },\n" +
                "                        {\n" +
                "                            \"boundingBox\": \"801,472,53,73\",\n" +
                "                            \"text\": \"IS\"\n" +
                "                        }\n" +
                "                    ]\n" +
                "                },\n" +
                "                {\n" +
                "                    \"boundingBox\": \"519,563,375,74\",\n" +
                "                    \"words\": [\n" +
                "                        {\n" +
                "                            \"boundingBox\": \"519,563,149,74\",\n" +
                "                            \"text\": \"JUST\"\n" +
                "                        },\n" +
                "                        {\n" +
                "                            \"boundingBox\": \"683,564,41,72\",\n" +
                "                            \"text\": \"A\"\n" +
                "                        },\n" +
                "                        {\n" +
                "                            \"boundingBox\": \"741,564,153,73\",\n" +
                "                            \"text\": \"WISH\"\n" +
                "                        }\n" +
                "                    ]\n" +
                "                }\n" +
                "            ]\n" +
                "        }\n" +
                "    ]\n" +
                "}";

            Rootobject r = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(val);
        }
    }
}
```

This is posted at [Rextester](https://rextester.com/CJFCL64835)

Comment: When I  Console.WriteLine(r);  all I get is is ConsoleApp2.Rootobject

Comment: That's because it has been *deserialized* into a `Rootobject` object. Now you have to do something with that object. For example, iterate through the `region`s and the `line`s and the `word`s

Comment: @Wesam Here is a complete example with the loops: https://dotnetfiddle.net/h8ldcy